# Filter list - logic issue

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to find the matching records of the following 2 List.

I have List called `allAnimals` : `Animal` and another List called `domesticAnimals` : `Animal`.

Now, I need to do a comparison between the 2 list and return a list where the `animalId` is equal.

```
    const commonList = this.allAnimals.filter(item1 => 
      this.domesticAnimals.find(item2 => item1.animalId=== item2.animalId)); 

      console.log("common anumal count is "+ commonList.length);
```

When I print the count, it gives me the count of the `allAnimals` and not the `commonList` . How can I solve this ?

```
**Animal Model**

animalId
animalName
animalAge
```

allAnimals

```
[{"animalId":1 , "animalName":"elephant"},
{"animalId":2 , "animalName":"elephant1"},
{"animalId":3 , "animalName":"ant"}]
```

domesticAnimals

```
[{"animalId":2 , "animalName":"elephant1"}]
```

Comment: Your code seems correct to me, would be able to give the data for `allAnimals ` and `domesticAnimals`?

Comment: @xyz I have added the model for Animal

Comment: No, I meant the list your looping, not the type

Comment: If you could give the `console.log` of `allAnimals` and `domesticAnimals`, would be great.

Comment: For your example, the codes works, it returns an array with one element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is sound. See below:

```js
const myAnimals = ['Donkey', 'Moose', 'Cat', 'Dog'];
const domesticAnimals = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'Bunny', 'Lizard', 'Goldfish'];

const myDomesticAnimals = myAnimals.filter(
  myAnimal => domesticAnimals.find(
    domesticAnimal => domesticAnimal === myAnimal
  )
);

console.log(myDomesticAnimals);

/*  Expected Output (the intersection of the two lists):

  [
    "Cat",
    "Dog"
  ]

*/
```

It may be that your two arrays contain the same elements, therefore the filter is not reducing by any.

### Edit

Given your provided data:

```js
const allAnimals = [
  {
    "animalId": 1,
    "animalName": "elephnat"
  },
  {
    "animalId": 2,
    "animalName": "elephnat1"
  },
  {
    "animalId": 3,
    "animalName": "ant"
  }
];

const domesticAnimals = [{
  "animalId": 2,
  "animalName": "elephnat1"
}];

const allDomesticAnimals = allAnimals.filter(
  animal => domesticAnimals.find(
    domesticAnimal => domesticAnimal.animalId === animal.animalId
  )
);

console.log(allDomesticAnimals);

/*  Expected Output (the intersection of the two lists):

  [
    {
      "animalId": 2,
      "animalName": "elephnat1"
    }
  ]

*/
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try below:** 
*Single line of code, Hopefully, You like this.!

```
 const result = allAnimals.filter(item => domesticAnimals.some(entry => entry.animalId == item.animalId));
```

Comment: Didn't you mean `filter(item => domesticAnimals.some(entry => entry.animalId == item.animalId))`?